# Adding contributor Azure subscription in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

My Azure account having one subscription is added as a contributor to another Azure account. Using `Login-AzureRmAccount` in PowerShell, I login to my account and `Get-AzureSubscription` returns only my own subscription. On the Azure portal, I can switch between these two subscriptions and create/remove resources on the other subscription.

I have checked `Select-AzureSubscription`, and it can be used in case `Get-AzureSubscription` returns multiple accounts to choose among them.

I also do not have the credentials of the other account to login manually.

Is there any way to access my contributor-role subscription in PowerShell and run Azure scripts on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Contributor" is an RBAC (Role based access control) role, so you have access to the subscription throught Azure Resource Manager. 
To find this subscription in PowerShell, you can use the *Get-AzureRmSubscription* cmdlet instead of *Get-AzureSubscription*. Then you can use the cmdlet *Select-AzureRmSubscription* to select the subscription instead of *Select-AzureSubscription*.